# Availability Groups Service Account has over 25000 sessions open

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, availability-groups, high-availability

I am running Availability Groups on SQL Server 2014 with one database in the group. Today, the server was responding very slowly and when I got on the server I found that the Availability Groups service account had over 25000 sessions open. Every session was to the MSDB database with the same query,  The query was:

```
(@P1 nvarchar(max),
 @P2 uniqueidentifier,
 @P3 int,
 @P4 int,
 @P5 int)
DECLARE @logTextWithPreAndPost nvarchar(max) set @logTextWithPreAndPost = N'' + @P1 + N''; 
EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_agent_write_sysjobstep_log 
 @job_id = @P2, 
 @is_system = @P3, 
 @step_id = @P4, 
 @log_text = @logTextWithPreAndPost, 
 @append_to_last=@P5
```

Does anyone know why it would hold so many sessions open or what I can do to stop it.

Comment: At a guess, you've got the same service account for the Server Agent as for the SQL Server service. If so, I suggest taking a look at the scheduled jobs on your instances (the `msdb` proc you reference is called by the Agent during job execution). Runing [sp_blitz](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/) can also tell you if you've got a [busy agent](https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/agent-jobs-starting-simultaneously/)

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you have enabled the `Log to table` option in the agent job step.

Run

```
SELECT spid, 
       program_name,  
       db_name(dbid) AS databasename
FROM   sys.sysprocesses 
WHERE  spid > 50
```

or if you have `sp_whoisactive` installed (http://whoisactive.com/)

```
EXEC sp_whoisactive 
     @output_column_list = '[%dd%][session_id][sql_text][%database%][login_name][program_name]' /* if they are sleeping spids, add @show_sleeping_spids = 2*/
```

Get the `uniqueidentifier` of the job from the program_name, then run

```
SELECT name
FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs 
WHERE  CONVERT(BINARY(16), job_id)=0x[id]
```

Replace `0x[id]` with your id. Once you get the job name, go to the job step, then un-check the `log to table` option.